# Error using jsonobject.count and pairs

Tags: json, delphi

I want to process a json string by following example:

```
{"colors":[{"name":"red","hex":"#f00"},{"name":"blue","hex":"#xxx"}]}
```

I tried different variants, and get the following errors:

> Tjsonobject does not contain a member named 'Count' at line...
>   Tjsonobject does not contain a member named 'Pairs' at line...
>   Undeclared identifier JsonString...

I put on uses the DBXJson
Delphi 10.2.3, vcl application

The code is:

```
var
o: TJSONObject;
  a: TJSONArray;
  book: TJSONObject;
  idx: integer;
  idy: integer;
begin
o := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Memo1.Lines.Text),0) as TJSONObject;
  try
    a := TJSONArray(o.Get('colors').JsonValue);
    for idx := 0 to pred(a.size) do begin
      book := TJSONObject(a.Get(idx));
      for idy := 0 to pred(book.Count) do begin
        ShowMessage( book.Pairs[idy].JsonString.ToString + ':' + book.Pairs[idy].JsonValue.ToString );
      end;
    end;
  finally
    o.Free;
  end;
end;
```

NEW IN JSON, is for learning but i can not figure out

Comment: Replace `DBXJson` by `System.JSON` (or just `JSON`).

Comment: I get another error: Cannot resolve unit name 'System.Json'  or 'Json'

Comment: On Delphi XE5, i get the same error

Comment: On Delphi 10.2.3 resolved by reinstallation of Delphi, but on XE5 the problem remains

Comment: System.JSON did not exist in XE5 AFAIK.

Comment: Ok. I Know. For XE5 in use is DBXJson. After changing the problem persists

Comment: You are using System.JSON property/field names. Presumibly the equivalent names in DBXJson are different. I would CTRL+Click on TJCONObject to see the definition, and see if I could see the equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question and comments are contradictory. Your question says you are using Delphi 10.2.3, but your comments say you are using XE5.

In Delphi 10.2.3, use the `System.JSON` unit. In XE5, use the `Data.DBXJson` unit.

If you read the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.DBXJSON.TJSONObject) for the XE5 version of `TJSONObject`, it does not have `Count` and `Pairs` properties, hence the errors you are seeing in your inner loop. You should be using the [`TJSONObject.Size`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.DBXJSON.TJSONObject.Size) property and [`TJSONObject.Get()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.DBXJSON.TJSONObject.Get) method instead, like your outer loop is already using, eg:

```
var
  o: TJSONObject;
  a: TJSONArray;
  book: TJSONObject;
  p: TJSONPair;
  idx: integer;
  idy: integer;
begin
  o := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Memo1.Lines.Text),0) as TJSONObject;
  try
    a := o.Get('colors').JsonValue as TJSONArray;
    for idx := 0 to pred(a.Size) do
    begin
      book := a.Get(idx).JsonValue as TJSONObject;
      for idy := 0 to pred(book.Size) do
      begin
        p := book.Get(idy);
        ShowMessage(p.JsonString.ToString + ':' + p.JsonValue.ToString);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    o.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively, `TJSONArray` and `TJSONObject` in both XE5 and 10.2.3 have `Enumerator` support, so you can use `for..in` loops instead, eg:

```
var
  o: TJSONObject;
  a: TJSONArray;
  book: TJSONObject;
  v: TJSONValue;
  p: TJSONPair;
begin
  o := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Memo1.Lines.Text),0) as TJSONObject;
  try
    a := o.Get('colors').JsonValue as TJSONArray;
    for v in a do
    begin
      book := v as TJSONObject;
      for p in book do
      begin
        ShowMessage(p.JsonString.ToString + ':' + p.JsonValue.ToString);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    o.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are learning how to use json in delphi, i would advise you to not use system.json, too complicated and very slow. take a look at TalJsonDocument at https://github.com/Zeus64/alcinoe

```
MyJsonDoc.loadFromJson('{"colors":[{"name":"red","hex":"#f00"},{"name":"blue","hex":"#xxx"}]}');
for i := 0 to MyJsonDoc.childnodes['colors'].ChildNodes.count - 1 do begin
  writeln(MyJsonDoc.childnodes['colors'].childnodes[i].childnodes['name'].text);
  writeln(MyJsonDoc.childnodes['colors'].childnodes[i].childnodes['hex'].text);
end;
```

Comment: yes, https://svn.code.sf.net/p/alcinoe/code/demos/ALJsonDoc/win32/AljsonDocDemo.exe and the sample data https://svn.code.sf.net/p/alcinoe/code/demos/ALJsonDoc/sample.json ... and you will see that Json in delphi is horribly (but really horribly) slow and 3 ms with TalJsonDoc when you have even out of memory with DBXJson